# Infinite scroll for angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, angularjs-ng-repeat

For infinite scroll I have written a piece of code in Javascript which detects the end of the window:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
          console.log("loading another page")
           
          $scope.loadMoreLiveFeed();
          
            
    }
 });
```

I get feed of 100 posts in JSON. I divide it in chunks of 10 and then call `loadMoreFeed` function whenever we scroll down, but to show that we are loading posts I have introduced a delay of 1 sec in `loadMoreLiveFeed` code using `$timeout`, so that I can have that loading effect.

The issue is when I add this delay my function `loadMoreLiveFeed` gets called twice; as soon as I remove the delay `loadMoreLiveFeed` function gets called once.
I am not getting why the call is happening twice.

Here is my `loadMoreLiveFeed` function:

```
 $scope.loadMoreLiveFeed = function() {
    
    if(scrollFlag && counter<20){
    $(".loader").show();
    $(".viewAll").hide();
    
    timer = $timeout(function() {
    for(var i =0; i<10; i++);
    
    }, 500);
    
    
    timer = $timeout(function() {
        
    if( $scope.tempPosts!= null)
    {
        
        for(var i =(10*counter); i < ((10*counter)+10) && counter < 20; i++) 
        {       console.log($scope.tempPosts[i].nid +"   " +counter);
            
                $scope.posts.push($scope.tempPosts[i]);
            
        }
        if(counter>=10){scrollFlag=false;}
        counter++;
         
        
    }
    
    $(".loader").hide();
    $(".viewAll").show();
    
    }, 1000);
    
  
 }
}
```

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a tested directive that will do exactly this.

Take a look at this: https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll

Comment: I am using it but with nginfinitescroll has issues with scroll positions its not working for me as it should.Any way i solved the issue thanks for your help

Comment: Cool, post answer to your question with solution. It may help someone else in future.

Comment: i did i was hiding and showing viewall divs with hide and show functions on every call . Ideally view all posts link should come after all feed will load. so i just added that if check and it worked. magical i would say

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue i just added a if condition to show view all div after all feeds are loaded and it worked. The calls got synchronised automatically. i just changed this bit at the end of loadMoreLiveFeed function

```
if (counter >= 10) {
  $('.loader').hide();
  $('.viewAll').show();
}
```